# How to print dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Given the following data frame:

```
          Name   Telephone  Telephone2
0   Bill Gates  555 77 854  555 77 855
1  Bill Gates2           2           3
```

How can I have exactly the following output(printing column by column)?

```
Name
Bill Gates
Bill Gates2
Telephone
555 77 854
2
Telephone2
555 77 855
3
```

I tried:

```
for key, val in df.iterrows():
    for sub_val in val:
        print(sub_val)
```

But I get:

```
Bill Gates
555 77 854
555 77 855
Bill Gates2
2
3
```

Comment: iterate over each column with `for col in df.columns:` and you can do `print(*df[col])`

Comment: @BijayRegmi not exactly what I want, the rest of the values are printed in one row... There is no way to know how to seperate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
for col in df:
    print(col)
    print('\n'.join(df[col]))
```

Output:

```
Name
Bill Gates
Bill Gates2
Telephone
555 77 854
2
Telephone2
555 77 855
3
```